# Storing handles to objects in a hashmap or set in Google's V8 engine

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I would like to implement this functionality in an embedded JavaScript application that uses v8 engine.

```
function myFunction1() {
   //do stuff
}

function myFunction2() {
   //do other stuff
}

myAddon.addCallback(myFunction1);
myAddon.addCallback(myFunction2);
myAddon.removeCallback(myFunction1);
```

In order to do this I need to store these functions in a `std::set` like so

```
void addCallback(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
   v8::HandleScope scope(args.GetIsolate());
   v8::Local<v8::Function> cb = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
   std::set mySet = this->mySet;
   //now how do I insert a reference to this function into mySet so I can retrieve
   //it later
}

void removeCallback(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
   v8::HandleScope scope(args.GetIsolate());
   v8::Local<v8::Function> cb = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
   std::set mySet = this->mySet;
   //now how do I remove the element in this set that refers to this function?
}
```

How does one go about doing this? I don't want to use [`v8::Object::GetIdentityHash()`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Object.html#a5309f7a349feb906a05ee45b6feeaab1) because the result is not guaranteed to be unique.

I also can't just store the Local in the `std::set` because the copy constructor is private and it would also get descoped once removeCallback or addCallback return.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: I realize I could write some javascript to do the function hashing for me, and then call one C++ binded function to iteration through all the callbacks, but I'd rather not do this every time I need to store sets or hashes of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Better to edit your question with that comment @robot_guy as its harder to miss.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct that you can't safely store `Local<T>` handle, because when it gets out of scope, your function object may become available to garbage collection. What you need is a persistent handle. You can construct it out of local like:

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> cb = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>> value(isolate, cb);
```

Note `CopyablePersistentTraits` which allows handle copying. There is also `NonCopyablePersistentTraits` if you would like to prevent that.

Now you can put it in a vector:

```
std::vector<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>>> v;
v.push_back(value);
```

Convert back to local:

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> local = v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(isolate, value);
```

For `std::set` you also need to provide comparison function for elements. It also might be a good idea to wrap `v8::Persistent<T>` into your own class like `PersistentWrapper<T>` (this is what I am doing in my project) to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are correct, those would have to be persistent objects so they wouldn't lose scope. Can you provide an example of how you wrap Persistent? Thanks

Comment: For example https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8565705 (c++11). I don't need objects hashing though. Is the only reason for hashing that you can remove callback later?