# Can't add a Persistent<Function> to vector<Persistent<Function>>

Tags: c++, v8

I'm migrating from v8 3.x to 4.y and I'm having problems with one of the functions defined in one of my header file.

```
//JavascriptBase.h
namespace Company {
    class Base {
      protected:
        void registerHandler(v8::Persistent<v8::Function>& func) {
            user_functions_.push_back(func);
        }
      private:
        std::vector<v8::Persistent<v8::Function>> user_functions_;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
third-party2/v8/4.7.39/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/281a9e6/include/v8.h:667:53: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Primitive *'
    while (false) { *(static_cast<O* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<Primitive*>(0); };
                                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
third-party2/v8/4.7.39/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/281a9e6/include/v8.h:663:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>::Uncompilable<v8::Object>' requested here
    Uncompilable<Object>();
    ^
third-party2/v8/4.7.39/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/281a9e6/include/v8.h:7175:6: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>::Copy<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >' requested here
  M::Copy(that, this);
     ^
third-party2/v8/4.7.39/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/281a9e6/include/v8.h:729:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >::Copy<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >' requested here
    Copy(that);
    ^
third-party2/libgcc/4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/8aac7fc/include/c++/4.8.1/ext/new_allocator.h:120:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >::Persistent' requested here
 { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                      ^
third-party2/libgcc/4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/8aac7fc/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > >::construct<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >, const v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > &>' requested here
 { __a.construct(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
third-party2/libgcc/4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/8aac7fc/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > > >::_S_construct<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >, const v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > &>' requested here
 { _S_construct(__a, __p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
   ^
third-party2/libgcc/4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1-glibc-2.17-fb/8aac7fc/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_vector.h:905:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > > >::construct<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >, const v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > &>' requested here
     _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                    ^
./Company/JavaScriptBase.h:84:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >, std::allocator<v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> > > >::push_back' requested here
    user_functions_.push_back(func);
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

I've done some googling and found that `Persistent` objects aren't assignable but I'm not sure what to do with this information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing handles to objects in a hashmap or set in Google's V8 engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239249/storing-handles-to-objects-in-a-hashmap-or-set-in-googles-v8-engine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they aren't assignable then you (obviously) can't assign them. And since `std::vector<>` relies on copying values using the assignment operator, your approach won't work.

You can however store pointers to them instead, since copying pointers of anything is well defined.

Comment: Technically, copying dangling/invalid pointers is undefined. But I suppose those are not pointers of things. :)

Comment: Is that true? I get that the standard is trying to pretend pointers are some kind of special magical construct and not just a bunch of numbers as it's most common nowadays, but what difference would the fact that it's an invalid pointer do?

Comment: @SergeyA: You may debate it all you like :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, not me, no. But I've heard people arguing about that, i.e., is it really undefined behaviour to copy a value of invalid pointer to another pointer without dereferencing it or not.

Comment: @SergeyA: People argue about a lot of things.

Comment: @Blindy: Trap representations, for one.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copyable persistent with this "typedef"

```
using CopyablePersistent = v8::Persistent<T, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<T>>;
```

This assumes it's inside a templated class, but you can make the T whatever you want.

edit: apparently this is a "very bad" thing to do, but I don't know why.

Comment: Why it's a "very bad" thing? Could you provide link to the source?

Comment: Nope.  Just been told that by devs in #v8 on freenode.  They said it will lead to intermittent crashes.  It's really never needed, though.  You can pass around Global& in your code and for use in STL containers or you can always make a new one with Global's normal constructors, too.